# Procedure no MySql para clonar produtos, Utilizando CURSOR FOR SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, procedure

Preciso clonar os dados de uma tabela EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA da empresa do id x para a mesma tabela mas da empresa com id y. no Pl/Sql fiz dessa maneira.

```
DECLARE

  CURSOR v_precos IS SELECT ID_PRODUTO, PRECO_CUSTO, PRECO_CUSTO_FINAL FROM erp.EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA where id_empresa = x and PRECO_CUSTO>0;

BEGIN   

FOR v_preco IN v_precos LOOP

  UPDATE erp.EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA SET PRECO_CUSTO = v_preco.PRECO_CUSTO, PRECO_CUSTO_FINAL = v_preco.PRECO_CUSTO_FINAL
  WHERE ID_PRODUTO = v_preco.ID_PRODUTO AND ID_EMPRESA = y;

  END LOOP;

END;
```

mas no mySql não consigo estou utilizando mySql 5.7 e acho que estou limitado as soluçoes.

ja tentei com uma modo estranho mas como n consegui fazer um foreach como no oracle so conseguia usar variaveis sem ter acesso ao objeto em si.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE preco_test() 
BEGIN   
    DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_id_produto INT ;
    DECLARE v_preco_custo double(15,5) ;
    DECLARE v_preco_custo_final double(15,5) ;

    DECLARE v_produto CURSOR  FOR SELECT ID_PRODUTO FROM EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA where id_empresa = x  and PRECO_CUSTO>0;
    DECLARE v_p_custo CURSOR  FOR SELECT PRECO_CUSTO FROM EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA where id_empresa = x  and PRECO_CUSTO>0;
    DECLARE v_p_custo_final CURSOR  FOR SELECT PRECO_CUSTO_FINAL  FROM EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA where id_empresa = x  and PRECO_CUSTO>0;


-- declare NOT FOUND handler
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

    OPEN v_produto;
    OPEN v_p_custo;
    OPEN v_p_custo_final;

        get_precos: LOOP

            FETCH v_produto INTO v_id_produto;
            FETCH v_p_custo INTO v_preco_custo;
            FETCH v_p_custo_final INTO v_preco_custo_final;


             IF v_finished =0 THEN 
             LEAVE get_precos;
             END IF;

                    UPDATE erp.EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA SET PRECO_CUSTO = v_preco_custo, PRECO_CUSTO_FINAL = v_preco_custo_final
                    WHERE ID_PRODUTO = v_id_produto AND ID_EMPRESA = y ;


        END LOOP get_precos;

    CLOSE v_produto;
CLOSE v_p_custo;
CLOSE v_p_custo_final;
END;
```

executava sem erro mas n alterava nada.

depois achei um modo que acho que faz um papel do ForEach

```
CREATE PROCEDURE preco_test() 
BEGIN   
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE v_precos CURSOR FOR SELECT ID_PRODUTO, PRECO_CUSTO, PRECO_CUSTO_FINAL FROM EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA where id_empresa = x and PRECO_CUSTO>0;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;
  DECLARE v_preco CURSOR FOR v_precos OPEN v_preco;

    FETCH v_preco INTO ;
    WHILE done=0
            DO

                    UPDATE EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA SET PRECO_CUSTO = v_preco.PRECO_CUSTO, PRECO_CUSTO_FINAL = v_preco.PRECO_CUSTO_FINAL 
                    WHERE ID_PRODUTO = v_preco.ID_PRODUTO AND ID_EMPRESA = y ;

                FETCH v_precos INTO;
        END WHILE;

 CLOSE
 FETCH v_precos INTO v_preco;
 END;
```

mas da erro de sintax

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'v_precos OPEN v_preco;

RESUMO: Estou alterando dados de uma tabela para os dados da mesma tabela mas de parametros diferente. não estou inserindo!

Update com Inner join seria uma boa pratica ?

Alguém pode dar uma ajuda?

Comment: Solução: <code> UPDATE EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA p1
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID_PRODUTO, PRECO_CUSTO, PRECO_CUSTO_FINAL FROM EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA where ID_EMPRESA = X  and PRECO_CUSTO>0) x1
ON p1.ID_PRODUTO = x1.ID_PRODUTO and p1.ID_EMPRESA = Y
SET p1.PRECO_CUSTO = x1.PRECO_CUSTO , p1.PRECO_CUSTO_FINAL = x1.PRECO_CUSTO_FINAL  </code>

Comment: Cara, já que você conseguiu chegar à resposta sozinho, aconselho à escrever uma resposta para sua própria pergunta e marca-la como correta para auxiliar outros que tenham o mesmo problema. Não tem problema responder à própria pergunta, isto inclusive é incentivado.

Comment: ok, respondi a própria pergunta pq uma vez escrevi uma resposta nova e uma pessoa me falou o contraria que vc kk.

Answer (score 0):

Solução: `UPDATE EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA p1 INNER JOIN (SELECT ID_PRODUTO, PRECO_CUSTO, PRECO_CUSTO_FINAL FROM EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA where ID_EMPRESA = X and PRECO_CUSTO>0) x1 ON p1.ID_PRODUTO = x1.ID_PRODUTO and p1.ID_EMPRESA = Y SET p1.PRECO_CUSTO = x1.PRECO_CUSTO , p1.PRECO_CUSTO_FINAL = x1.PRECO_CUSTO_FINAL`